# mysql using incorrect index on large table

Tags: mysql

**The Problem**

I have a table that's about 2 million rows (at 115 MB) and it's about to be much larger.  When running some utility scripts on the table I noticed one of my queries was taking a long time (15+ seconds) when a query that was nearly identical took less than a half second right before.  Here are the queries:

Query 1:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `my_table` WHERE `my_column`='test' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 28000, 1000
Execution time: 0.204 seconds
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `my_table` WHERE `my_column`='test' ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 29000, 1000
Execution time: 10.203 seconds
```

**Indexing and table info**

`id` is a primary key and `my_column` is also indexed (although at the moment its cardinality is only 1)

• id is an int
• my_column is a varchar(50)

**Queries explained**

Query 1: **type**: index, **possible_keys**: my_column, **key**: PRIMARY, **key_len**: 4, **rows**: 29,000, **Extra**: Using where

Query 2: **type**: range, **possible_keys**: my_column, **key**: my_column, **key_len:** 53, **rows**: 2,139,123 **Extra**: Using where; Using filesort

As you can see the 2nd query is using the `my_column` key and filesort and taking forever, but all I did was increment the limit offset by 1,000.

**How I temporarily fixed the problem**

1) If I remove the `WHERE my_column = 'test'` condition the mysql optimizer correctly uses the primary key to sort, but I can't remove this condition because soon enough there will be other values in `my_column` which I'm going need to filter out for this query.

2) If I use `FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)` the mysql optimizer will also use the proper index, but this seems to be sort of a hack.

**My question**

Why exactly is mysql choosing to use the `my_column` index instead of the primary key?  And is there a better way to handle this either in the table definition, indexes, or my query structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try creating a [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on the combination of `(my_column, id)`.

Comment: Sigh...I just love dumb oversight.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

That is strange. Have you tried adding a composite index?

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD INDEX  (id, my_column);
```

If you are only selecting id and always only using my_column in the where clause this should work good.

Comment: You'd want `my_column` to be the leftmost column of the composite index since it is the one being tested in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

With your current set up, there are two obvious ways to execute the query.

1. Retrieve the rows in `id` order and throw away the ones that fail to match the `WHERE` clause.
2. Retrieve the rows that match the `WHERE` clause and sort them in `id` order.

Presumably MySQL is guessing which way to use based on how many rows you want.

However, if you create an index on both `my_column` and `id`, MySQL can then retrive the rows in `my_column, id` order, starting at the first row where `my_column = 'test'`.

Note that in the general case this requires all the conditions in the `WHERE` clause to be equality and all the columns in the `WHERE` clause to exist in the index.